# In ada programming language, Is there a way to create a subtype which takes differently positioned enums of a type?

Tags: ada, subtype

I am trying create a subtype which takes certain enumerations of a type for example,

```ada
type Integers_Type is (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

I want something like this,

```ada
subtype Odd_Numbers_Type is Integers_Type (1,3,5,7,9);
```

I understand that when we use the keyword `subtype` of a type we need to use range, but the problem is the enumeration is not in a series.

Comment: Unless I've missed something, your `Integers_Type` declaration is not valid. The elements of an enumerated type have to be identifiers (or character literals), not numbers. `type Integers_Type is range 1..10;` would be legal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this kind of values filtering, I would use [subtype predicates](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-2-4.html#I1437).

In your case, modifying your enumeration according to what Keith said :

```vhdl
type Integers_Type is (ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TEN);

subtype Odd_Numbers_Type is Integers_Type 
   with Static_Predicate => Odd_Numbers_Type in ONE | THREE | FIVE | SEVEN | NINE;
```

If you want to use numeric types instead of enumeration, use the following

```vhdl
type Integers_Type is range 1 .. 10;

subtype Odd_Numbers_Type is Integers_Type
   with Dynamic_Predicate => Odd_Numbers_Type mod 2 /= 0;
```

For more information, you can read [the rationale](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-2-5.html)

EDIT :

For Enumeration types, the following compiles using *gnatmake -gnata -gnatVa test_enum.adb* but warns about the affectation line 14 and fails at execution because of the assert linked to the static predicate.

```vhdl
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

Procedure Test_Enum is
   type Integers_Type is (ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TEN);

   subtype Odd_Numbers_Type is Integers_Type 
     with Static_Predicate => Odd_Numbers_Type in ONE | THREE | FIVE | SEVEN | NINE;
   
   Test_I : Integers_Type := TWO;
   Test_O : Odd_Numbers_Type := ONE;
begin
   Put_Line("Test_I=" & Integers_Type'Image (Test_I));
   Put_Line ("Test_O=" & Odd_Numbers_Type'Image (Test_O));
   Test_O := Test_I;
   Put_Line ("Test_O=" & Odd_Numbers_Type'Image (Test_O));
end Test_Enum;
```

For integer types, using the *gnatmake -gnata -gnatVa test_int.adb* compilation command, the compiler warns that the check will fail at runtime which is the case as the assertion is triggered.

```vhdl
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

Procedure Test_Int is
   type Integers_Type is range 1 .. 10;

   subtype Odd_Numbers_Type is Integers_Type
     with Dynamic_Predicate => Odd_Numbers_Type mod 2 /= 0;
   
   Test_I : Integers_Type := 2;
   Test_O : Odd_Numbers_Type := 1;
begin
   Put_Line("Test_I=" & Integers_Type'Image (Test_I));
   Put_Line ("Test_O=" & Odd_Numbers_Type'Image (Test_O));
   Test_O := Test_I;
   Put_Line ("Test_O=" & Odd_Numbers_Type'Image (Test_O));
end Test_Int;
```

In both cases, removing the *-gnata* flag will make the program working without taking care of the predicate as asserts are desactivated.

Comment: But I just tested it and using Gnat CE 2019, it does

Comment: And both examples also compile using Gnat 9.1.0 from Ubuntu 19.04 and behave the same way at execution... So maybe you downvoted me a little too quickly

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I misread it as mixing an enumeration type and an integer type.

Comment: Thanks frederic, I totally appreciate the explanation as it works like charm and I did not have the compilation problem in the version of GNAT compiler i am using.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing enumerations and integers, this is a *big* difference if you're coming from something like C: in Ada enumerations are **not** merely labels for integers.

The answer given by Frédéric Praca is absolutely correct, but (a) you can use the `Static_Predicate` on numeric-types; and (b) there's a way to do what you ask in the question's title which is subtly different than what you're asking in the question-body.

The problem with using subtype-predicates is that you lose the ability to use certain

(a) — `Static_Predicate`

```vhdl
Type Digit_Range is 0..9;
Subtype Odd_Digit is Digit_Range
  with Static_Predicate => 1|3|5|7|9;
```

(b) — Positions of an Enumeration
In Ada there are several attributes, among these are `Pos` & `Val`, and `Pred` & `Succ`. Given an enumeration (`Type Example is (A,B,C,D,E);`, you can say `Example'Pos(D)` which will return `3`, and you can say `Example'Val(1)` which will return `B`.

You *could* then combine things together to create multiple-types, though this *is* heavy-handed and not normally what you want to do.

```vhdl
Type Base_Numeric_Range is range 0..9;
Type Odds is range 1..Base_Numeric_Range'Pos(Base_Numeric_Range'Last)) - Base_Numeric_Range'Pos(Base_Numeric_Range'First)) / 2;

-- This is from memory, and untested; so probably wrong in the details.
Function Convert(X : Base_Numeric_Range) return Odds is
        ( Odds'Val((Base_Numeric_Range'Pos(X) / 2) + 1) );
Function Convert(X : Odds) return Base_Numeric_Range is
        ( Base_Numeric_Range'Val(Odds'Pos(X) * 2 - 1) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the idea was to provide an understandable example of the Question's title, more over i am a beginner in the Ada programming language so i could've given an ambiguous example.